# where can i find the Series 40 5th Edition SDK, Feature Pack 1 Lite for download?

Tags: sdk, java-me, nokia, nokia-s40

i need this nokia sdk but i can't find it anywhere on the internet. i tried to access the nokia forum site and it seems like it has been down for a long time it shows a message on my browser DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.

Does someone still have Series_40_5th_Edition_SDK_FP1_Lite_v1_0_en.zip or Series_40_5th_Edition_SDK_FP1_Lite_v0_9_en.zip

Answer (score 0):

Lucky for you it seems someone archived a few of these, I managed to track down Series 40 5th Edition SDK Feature Pack 1.1:
https://archive.org/download/nokia_sdks_n_dev_tools2/Series_40_5th_Edition_SDK_Feature_Pack_1_1_0.zip